# Como quebrar a linha da tabela com dados do mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá fiz um sisteminha de pedido mais gostaria de saber como posso fazer para quebrar a linha após as virgulas .Assim quando eu imprimir o pedido na cozinha ele venha da seguinte forma

Costela de  tambaqui : 1

Tabaqui Frito : 1

Fanta Laranja  : 1

Fanta laran ja 2l : 1

e a impressão venha mais organizada  o pedido e ao lado a quantidades .

Como poderia fazer , fico grato desde ja .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
                    <th >Comanda</th>
                    <th >N°Mesa</th>
                    <th >Refeição</th>
                    <th >Quantidade</th>
                    <th >Bebida</th>
                    <th >Quantidade</th>
                    <th  >Data</th>
                    <th >Acão</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td ">'.$row["id_pedido"].'</td>';
                echo '<td ">'.$row["numero_mesa"].'</td>';
                echo '<td  >'.$row["pedido_refeicao"].'</td>';
                echo '<td >'.$row["num_refeicao"].'</td>';
                echo '<td >'.$row["pedido_bebida"].'</td>';
                echo '<td >'.$row["num_bebida"].'</td>';
                echo '<td >'.date("d/m/y H:i:s", strtotime($row["data"])).'</td>';

                echo '</tr>';

            }
                ?>
                <td><a href="form_alteracao.php?codigo=<?php echo $dado["usu_codigo"];?>">editar</a>
    </tr>
    <thead>
<table>
```

Comment: poste o código que monta a tabela

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio JÁ FIZ

Comment: vc ainda não se acertou? veja se isso resolve seus problemas http://kithomepage.com/sos/ped.php

Answer (score 2):

Tem que manipular a string antes de imprimí-la usando algumas funções dentro de um ciclo

```
<?php
$str = "abc, xyz, 123";

for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
  $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
  if ($char == ","){
    $str = substr_replace($str, "<br>", $i+1, 0);
  }
}

echo "$str";
?>
```

Para esse código o output é:

```
abc,
xyz,
123
```